# thymeleaf doesn't update a model value in my template after a post

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a session attribute called

@SessionAttributes("myNewAttribute")

which is defined at the top of my controller. when I hit my second endpoint, the post, the value does not update in thymleaf from blank to showing the string but it does print it to my console. I'm going a little crazy. Here is my controller file and my template:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("myNewAttribute")
public class SpringFileController {
@GetMapping("/pageone")
    public String displayPageOne(Model model) {


        return "pageone";
    }

    @PostMapping("/clickedsavebutton")
    public String handleSaveButton(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("myNewAttribute","catnip");

        String valueToDisplay = (String)model.getAttribute("myNewAttribute");
        System.out.println(valueToDisplay);

        return "pageone";
    }
}
```

my template

```
<p th:text="${myNewAttribute}"></p>

<!--the save button, other things, wtc.. -->
```

So in my console when I click save I get "catnip" but "catnip" is not displayed on the page UNTIL I refresh the page.  What am I doing wrong

edit: I added window.location.reload() after my post call in my template which makes the attribute show, but I lose other things on the page that have been changed if I do it this way

Comment: yes, you have to (re)load your page by calling your controller endpoints ( Thymeleaf will then process your Model attributes). I suspect that you're calling your endpoint via ajax, so your page doesn't get reloaded. Post the part of your code that makes that post request to /clickedsavebutton.

Comment: Please show your full page and not just a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior, Thymeleaf is a rendering engine and as such can not change things after the initial load of the page.

To get the desired effect you'd have to reload (part) of your web page. this can be either a complete refresh or refreshing a div or field using something like ajax/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```js
$( "#required-field-div" ).load(window.location.href + " #required-field-div" );
```

to my function on the save button and got this to work. thank you for all the help!

Comment: Which explains why it fails, as you are not using a regular form submit but rather a ajax (javascript) submit. Which happens in the background. You would need to replace the content then yourself (you will get the HTML as a response but you would need to replace the HTML content for the page yourself). If you would do a regular form submit you wouldn't need this (which is the part you left out in your question!).